# HTML using ASP issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

I am using a div element which is getting replaced by the ckeditor. The user enters some data in the editor and it is being saved in the database. I am retrieving back the data from DB and trying to display it in editor.Suppose if the user has entered a table in the editor it gets stored in db as

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 50px; height: 50px"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>.
```

Now when retrieved back from DB and shown in the page instead of displaying a table it displays as a text

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 50px; height: 50px"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

like this. But I want it to displayed as a table. Any idea of how to do this.

Comment: How can we know without codes? You want to do it on server side or client side ?

Comment: show how you retrieve data from db.

Comment: i am using asp classic and retrieving data as <%= rs(fieldname)%> or response.write rs("fieldname")

Comment: <% test1=server.htmlencode(request.form("test1")) set Conn = server.createobject("adodb.connection") constr = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1;Password=##;User ID=##; Initial Catalog=#####;Data Source=###.##.##.##" Conn.open constr conn.execute "insert into temptable (test1) values('"& test1 &"')" %> This is my submit page code which is after editor page and print code is

Comment: <% set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION") set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET") Con.Open "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1;Password=###;User ID=##; Initial Catalog=#####;Data Source=###.#;" rs.open "SELECT test1 from template",con if not (rs.eof and rs.bof) then end if %><%= rs("test1")%>

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the source..IN editors there is an option for toggle source code,  If it displays as text then toggle the code,it will display as table..

**HTML view**

[image]

**Code VIEW**

[image]

Comment: in database it is saving in html code and i want to print it on webpage basically i want to use it for my website content managment i done all admin panel and when iam edit this page and want to save it is saving in plain html format the time of printing it on webpage by using asp <%= rs("fieldname")%> or <% response.write rs("fieldname")%> fieldname is that column where i am saving data form ckeditor and want to retrive it is showing same code in page

Comment: Dear Sir, my database content is like <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 50px; height: 50px"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>. but i want to pritn in page in table format not like code now i am facing the same

Comment: ya thats what i say..when saving it in database,use html encode..when retrieving from database use html decode (display as table diagram)..

Comment: <%
 
test1=server.htmlencode(request.form("test1"))

set Conn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")

constr = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1;Password=##;User ID=##; Initial Catalog=#####;Data Source=###.##.##.##"
Conn.open constr

conn.execute "insert into temptable (test1) values('"& test1 &"')"
 
%>

This is my submit page code which is after editor page

and print code is

Comment: <%
   
   
set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
   
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")

Con.Open "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1;Password=###;User ID=##; Initial Catalog=#####;Data Source=###.#;"
   

rs.open "SELECT test1 from template",con

if not (rs.eof and rs.bof) then 
end if %><%= rs("test1")%>
it is printing as it is please help me out

Comment: it is showing "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'htmldecode'"

Comment: Done Thanks IT is working with replace encoded text to Html Text Thanks for help